# IBM RFT: object finder dissappears

Tags: rft

I am attempting to use object finder on RFT v9.1. It suddenly disappears when attempting to highlight a object. Is there something I need to do to correct this? It use to work and suddenly stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the RFT i have faced this issue too. 
 sry for late reply...

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with RFT; even with version 10.2.

What you can do is -

1. Restart machine
2. Go to Task manager -> Processes tab. And find your process, right click and Bring to front.

If you find any permanent solution, please reply.